# XML validation No declaration of element as matching wildcard is strict

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am creating an XML based on OGC based schema. The schema allows  to be accepted as an element for one of the tags.But after addition of tag the online Team engine validator throws The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element exception.
I have also declared the schema location for the custom element added but still, the same exception is thrown
 Kindly find below snippet of XML

```
     "<VendorSpecificCapabilities>
      <person xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="person.xsd"/>
       </VendorSpecificCapabilities>"
```

Even when the schema location for person tag is correct still the exception comes. 
Kindly note that the overall schema for `VendorSpecificCapabilities` cannot be changed/updated.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only attach a schema to the root element, not to a child element. So the (unfortunately read/only) main schema should be made complete.

Comment: I have even tried doing that. Vendor specific Capability tag has the following schema(and cannot be updated/changed)

Comment: <xs:element name="VendorSpecificCapabilities" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:any/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

Comment: As it accepts <xs:any> so i tried adding person tag with schema defined under person.xsd. Instead of declaring the schema location with person tag i added to the root element. Still no success